# disaggregating raster causes insufficient disk space

Tags: r, terra

I am trying to disaggregate a raster using `terra` package. My original raster is:

```
library(terra)
  
my_raster 
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 180, 360, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source      : EHF2_2020_max.nc_rotated.nc 
varname     : X2020 
name        : X2020
```

I want to drop the resolution to the following target raster

```
target_raster
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source      : GDP_PPP_30arcsec_v3.nc 
varname     : GDP_PPP (Gross Domestic Production (GDP) (PPP)) 
name        :                             GDP_PPP_3 
unit        : constant 2011 international US dollar
```

When I did this, I get below error:

```
disagg_raster <- disagg(my_raster, fact = c(21600,43200))
 
Error: [disagg] insufficient disk space (perhaps from temporary files?)
```

I have a fresh R session and other than these two objects, nothing else is loaded in my environment. What is causing this error?

However, when I disaggregate raster using `resample`, I do not get any memory issue

```
resample_raster <- resample(my_raster, target_raster, method='bilinear')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get below error:

```
disagg_raster <- disagg(my_raster, fact = c(21600,43200))
# Error: [disagg] insufficient disk space (perhaps from temporary files?)
```

That says there is not enough disk space to write the file. Output SpatRasters are are written to disk if they are deemed too large to keep in memory. As you do not provide a filename argument, the file would go to the `tempdir()` folder and that does not have enough disk space.

This is happening because you use trying to create a monster of a raster (easy to do and see for a raster that has no cell values):

```
library(terra)
r <- rast()
disagg(r, fact = c(21600,43200))
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 3888000, 15552000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 2.314815e-05, 4.62963e-05  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84
```

It appears that you misunderstood the `fact` argument. To get the spatial resolution of your target raster you can do:

```
disagg(r, fact = 120)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84
```

That is still big enough, but it should not create problems.